# In convective equilibrium prove the following result

Tags: applications, fluid-dynamics

**Question:** In convective equilibrium show that pressure $p$ at any height $z$ above the earth's surface is
$$p=p_0\left[ 1-\dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\left(\dfrac{1}{\rho_0^{\gamma-1}}\right)\dfrac{gz}{k}\right]^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}$$

**My approach:** Suppose the gravity $g$ is constant. Then the pressure equation becomes
\begin{equation}
dp=-\rho g\, dz \tag{1}
\end{equation}
In adiabatic condition,
\begin{equation}
p=k \rho^{\gamma}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
This implies 
\begin{equation}
dp=k\gamma \rho^{\gamma-1}\, d\rho\tag{3}
\end{equation}
From (1) and (3),
\begin{equation}
k\gamma \rho^{\gamma-1}d\rho=-\rho g \,dz
\end{equation}
Integrating and simplifying, 
$\dfrac{p}{\rho}\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\right)=C-gz$, $c=$ constant of integration.
From $p=\rho RT$,
\begin{equation}
RT\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\right)=C-gz \tag{4}
\end{equation}

At sea level, $z=0, T=T_0$, So we have
$$\dfrac{T}{T_0}=1-\dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\cdot \dfrac{gz}{RT_0}$$

How can I show the required result?

Comment: Can you give some background about the definition of the term "convective equilibrium"?

Comment: By convective equilibrium we mean a state of equilibrium in which if equial masses of air at any two stations be interchanged each would assume the pressure, density and temperature of the other. Thus the change takes place without loss or gain of heat, i.e., adiabatically.@Mann

Comment: Maybe don't introduce $p=\rho RT$ and just manipulate the solution directly, using (2) again.

Answer (score 1):

As you have done, integrating $k\gamma \rho^{\gamma-1}d\rho=-\rho g \,dz$ results in

$$\dfrac{p}{\rho}\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\right)=C-gz,$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration. Equivalently, since $p = k\rho^\gamma$ we have

$$k\rho^{\gamma-1}\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\right)=\dfrac{p}{\rho}\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\right)=C-gz,$$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{\gamma-1}{k\gamma}$ we get

$$\tag{1}\rho^{\gamma-1} = \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma} \frac{C}{k}- \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\dfrac{gz}{k}$$

Since $\left.\rho\right|_{z = 0} = \rho_0$ at sea level, substitution into (1) yields

$$\rho_0^{\gamma-1} =  \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma} \frac{C}{k} $$

Whence,

$$\tag{2}\rho^{\gamma-1} = \rho_0^{\gamma-1} - \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\dfrac{gz}{k} = \rho_0^{\gamma-1} \left[1 - \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{\rho_0^{\gamma-1}} \right)\dfrac{gz}{k} \right]$$

Note that $p = k\rho^\gamma$ implies $\rho = \frac{p^{1/\gamma}}{k^{1/\gamma}}$ and  $\rho_0 = \frac{p_0^{1/\gamma}}{k^{1/\gamma}}$. Substituting into (2) we get

$$\frac{p^{\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}}}{k^\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}}=   \frac{p_0^{\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}}}{k^\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}}\left[1 - \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{\rho_0^{\gamma-1}} \right)\dfrac{gz}{k}\right]$$

Multiplying both sides by $k^\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}$ and then raising both sides to the power $\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}$ yields the desired result

$$p =   p_0\left[1 - \dfrac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}\left(\frac{1}{\rho_0^{\gamma-1}} \right)\dfrac{gz}{k}\right]^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}$$